# WSO2 Message Broker - Authorization

Tags: wso2, authorization, mqtt, iot, messagebroker

I am trying to implement an authorization mechanism on WSO2 Message Broker, but I am pretty new to WSO2 products. My goal is to implement MQTT Topic Authorization in the same manner it is implemented for JMS topics. Actually I am looking the code on the "andes" repository and "carbon-business-messaging" repository, and I would be very grateful if you can suggest me where to start. (that's a lot of code to look at)

What I want to do is to allow a particular user to publish/subscribe topics using the User Role permissions, so that even if someone connects to the Broker, he/she can't subscribe or publish without permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the Authentication is happening in MQTT from [here](https://github.com/wso2/andes/blob/master/modules/andes-core/broker/src/main/java/org/dna/mqtt/moquette/messaging/spi/impl/ProtocolProcessor.java#L830).

You can look at the following method in ProtocolProcessor.java class. This is located in andes core.

```
processSubscribe(ServerChannel session, SubscribeMessage msg, String clientID, boolean cleanSession)
```

Also to get an idea about the how authorization Done in JMS messaging you can refer AndesAuthorizationHandler.java Class from [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-business-messaging/blob/master/components/andes/org.wso2.carbon.andes.authorization/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/andes/authorization/andes/AndesAuthorizationHandler.java). This is located in carbon-business-messaging repository.